# How should I deploy my micro-services in Azure?

Tags: azure

I am confused about how should I deploy my micro-services in azure? I did deploy by creating couple of app services for each of the micro-services. I deployed using the ARM template. It is becoming very costly to deploy every micro-service in different app service and very difficult to manage all these services. Another approach which i was thinking is create one service and could have deployed under one app service but it would be again monolithic kind of web API.

Recently, I got to know through one of the blogs that to deploy micro-services you should use Azure Service fabric.

I want to understand which way I should opt out of below options-

- One app service.
- Multiple micro-service in different app service.
- containerization with kubernetes(or other orchestrator)
- azure service fabric?
- Any other option which you suggest.

I am really confused about these. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: You can create multiple Web Apps on the same App Service plan.  You end up paying for only one plan.

Comment: Thank you for your time @CSharpRocks , but then I won't have an option to individually scale out/in services.

Comment: Scaling your microservices independently seams like a requirement for you as you mentioned it in two comments.  Please edit your question and add this information.

Answer (score 3):

I'd highly recommend starting with the [Azure Architecture Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/) which will give you a solid big-picture overview. From there, you could take a look at the [microservice-specific guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/).

To provide a very short, incomplete answer to your question, App Services are a unit of scale. If you're building a small service that focuses on [one domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/model/domain-analysis), and all of your functionality can scale together, you may be better off with one application hosted on one App Service. Know your domain first; don't split things up just to have microservices.

To choose which Azure compute service to use, [this decision tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree#choose-a-candidate-service) is very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for you time @sortofbusy. Yes, I definitely need to have microservices in my project in which we need to scale out/in individual services instead of all the services. I already went through that microservice-specific guidance but didn't get which one will be fit or I may have misunderstood something. Please guide me if I have to use microservice then which one will be best fit of the available options. Thank you !!

Comment: @Rahul I've edited my answer. If it works for you, please mark it as accepted!

Comment: One thing to add is grouping multiple apps under one plan is a good starting point, and be sure to include AppInsights from the so you can decide if you need to separate them in different Plans in the future if the usage pattern scenarios are different. The decision whether your functionality should live in one Web App (service) or multiple is better based on principle of Bounded Context where unit of change and business function are primary key reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Microservices are not only a solution to technological problems. They are also a solution to an organizational scalability problem. In the other hand, Microservices are really hard to manage, that is why usually they cannot be implemented without DevOps techniques to help to solve this problem.
I am saying all this because you wrote that they are becoming hard to manage, and it might be that the problem is not technical, but instead you don't have the right org structure and processes to handle microservices.

Microservices work well if the teams that builds it, runs it. And that includes deployment, support, etc. You should not have one person/team "handling" and deploying other's teams microservices, because as you discovered, microservices are really hard to manage

From a pure technological point of view, you need to clarify some stuffs:

1. How many microservice
2. How many teams/developers
3. What technologies are your microservices built in
4. How chatty these microservices are between each other

From those 4 questions, you probably end up in App Services if you have small amount of microservices and they do not need more than 10 instances each, are built in one of the supported technologies and your microservices are not super chatty to each other.
I would use AKS if you have a lot of microservices and many teams, so it is worth it to have a small platform team getting expert in kubernetes (not in charge of the deployments!)

I would recommend you to go through these links

1. Martin Fowler: https://martinfowler.com/microservices/
2. DevOps at Microsoft: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwiT59e0kB4&t=349s
3. Why not to do Microservices: https://segment.com/blog/goodbye-microservices/
4. Million microservices talks in youtube like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrV0DqTqpFU